# How to parse a 'String?' variable in Dart

Tags: dart, parsing

I am trying to parse an input with the type 'String?' into a double, but it is saying that -

The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

```
    stdout.write("Enter the first number - ");
    String? vari = stdin.readLineSync();
    var first = int.parse(vari);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
int? first = int.tryParse(vari.toString());
```

This is because `String?` is nullable, vs `String`.

- `.parse` functions require non-nullable Strings.
- `tryParse` returns an `int` if the string is parsable, and returns `null` if it can't be parsed. This is why I changed `var first` to `int? first`.
- You can check afterwards if `first` is null or not. You can also perform this check before parsing it, and your code would look like this:

```
 String? vari = stdin.readLineSync();
 if (vari != null) var first = int.parse(vari);
```

This would work.